# iPhone Generic bundle for application resources

Tags: objective-c, iphone, c-preprocessor, bundle, target

Have developed an iPhone app which has two different functionality and it using same images and string in some areas in both the project. Here I am using preprocessor macros which are differentiating it during compile time say for example project one and project two.

Here my question is is there any way to pass the images and string in generic way. I mean if I execute the application  for project one means it should only take relevant app's images and string it should not bundled with another project i.e. project two's source.

Any idea and suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the screenshot of a project that has two targets:

[image]

And at folder structure:

[image]

You can put shared assets in the `Shared` folder and add them to both targets like `SharedImage.png` in the example. For assets that has two different versions, you can put each version on the appropriate folder (`Target A` or `Target B`) and use the same name for both versions. For example, when adding the image `MyImage.png` to `Target A`, you simply have to check the box `Target A` like in the following screenshot:

[image]

Now, it is easy to use the correct asset for each target and without using preprocessor macros. For example, the following code will use the correct version of `MyImage.png` whether it is running in `Target A` or `Target B`

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"MyImage.png"];
```

Comment: Hey Sch thanks a lot for your response and have another question like is there any way to separate the strings and codes in project based on target like similar to images... ?

Comment: and also is it i can use the static library for images and strings for two different project ?

Comment: 1) You can use the same method to organize your code and other resources. 2) Unfortunately, you can't package resources inside a static library, but there are many tutorials on how to create a [universal framework](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework) where you can do that.